# How to get data attribute value using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am working on jquery with php,Right now i have button inside loop and i want to pass "data attribute" and want to get value,Right now i am getting "undefined",So how can i do this ?
Here is my current code

```
echo "<td>"."<a class='map-pop' data-id='".$employee_time['id']."' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#mapModal' onclick='viewmap();'><img src='assets/viewmap.png'></a>"."</td>";
                    
<script>
function viewmap()
{
     var ids = $(this).attr('data-id');
        alert('id is ' + ids);
}

</script>
```

Comment: Please use proper jQuery event handling methods, not inline event handlers set via onclick attributes.

Comment: As above, if you had correctly separated your markup from your js, `this` would be available.  Surprisingly, none of the suggested answers show how to add a basic click handler.  https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-basics/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your onclick to this

```
onclick='viewmap(this)'
```

and get data with jquery like this

```
function viewmap(elm){
  var id = $(elm).data('id');
  alert('id is ' + id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass **this** in onclick function and get in viewmap function and access
You can try below code ..

PHP

```
<?php

echo "<td>"."<a class='map-pop' data-id='".$employee_time['id']."' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#mapModal' onclick='viewmap(this);'><img src='assets/viewmap.png'></a>"."</td>";
         
?>
```

Script

```
<script>
function viewmap(m)
{
     var ids = m.attr('data-id');
        alert('id is ' + ids);
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using `this` inside your function `viewmap` but you are not sending it as a parameter from the `HTML` code, Change your `onclick` by: `onclick='viewmap(this);` than change the `js` function like bellow:

```js
function viewmap(e)
{
     var ids = $(e).attr('data-id');
     alert('id is ' + ids);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class='map-pop' data-id='1254' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#mapModal' onclick='viewmap(this);'>
  click here
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `onclick` attribute and change the `viemap()` function like this

```js
$(".map-pop").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  let ids = $(this).data('id');
  alert(`id is ${ids}`);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class='map-pop' data-id='".$employee_time['id']."' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#mapModal'><img src='assets/viewmap.png'></a>
```

`